# Layout quebrado ao receber medalha

Tags: bug, layout

Recebi recentemente uma nova medalha, ao acessar meu perfil para visualizá-la, me deparei com o `layout` da seguinte maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

URL da imagem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyMXu.png

Comment: Aqui também: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/316061/youve-earned-badge-panel-layouts-are-broken